# MonoDroid - Threading Anomaly in StartService

Tags: android, .net, multithreading, mono, xamarin.android

I'm asking this to gain deeper insight into the bowls of Mono for Android, and to be better prepared down the road when supporting my mobile app...

I noticed that when calling StartService from a worker thread started in the "main launcher" activity that the thread id in OnStartCommand of the service is the same as the activities thread id (1), and not the worker-thread's id that started it (3).

Here is a more abstract representation:

```
myActivity : Activity
{
  OnCreate
  {
    print_thread_id()  // 1

    start(thread_func) 
  }

  thread_func() 
  {
    print_thread_id()  // 3 (not 2!, but anyway ...)

    StartService(myService)
  }
}

myService : Service
{
  OnStartCommand
  {
    print_thread_id()   // 1 also!!!
  }
}
```

I've also noticed that within my worker thread, thread_func, that StartService returns even though the service continues to run.  I figured that the call to StartService would block until myService exits.

Why is the thread id in myService.OnStartCommand not the same as thread_func's, isn't thread_func its parent being that is where the call to StartService is made ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you starting the thread? Are you creating a System.Threading.Thread instance, using a System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing the behavior you describe. A method in a new thread accurately reports its own id. Here is a very simple class that may help you troubleshoot the differences in your environment:

```
namespace ThreadTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "ThreadTest", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            MyService service = new MyService();
            Console.WriteLine("First Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(service.StartCommand));
            oThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public class MyService : Android.App.Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public void StartCommand()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

First Thread id: 1

New Thread id: 4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks joates... I may have had a misunderstanding in proper Service usage.  Here is what I was doing:

```
namespace ThreadTest  
{  
  [Activity (Label = "ThreadTest", MainLauncher = true)]  
  public class myActivity : Activity  
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

      Console.WriteLine("Main Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 

      Thread serviceWorker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serviceThread));
      serviceWorker.Start();
    }

    private void serviceThread()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Child Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 

      StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(myService)));
    }
  }

  public class myService : Service
  {
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Service Thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
    }
  }
}
```

Is this wrong, or just a different approach ?  Would this be the correct way if one were to use the StartService method to fire off a service, instead of how you started it above ?

In the way you have suggested, your assigning a method of the Service object to a worker thread within the main activity, and then launching it via ThreadStart().  My approach is actually firing off the service itself via StartService (the only reason I'm calling from within a child thread is so that the UI doesn't get blocked, not b/c its required).

The way I presented seems proper in the sense that I am letting adroid/mono manage the loading and calling of the service (StartService will eventually cause the override OnStartCommand to get called). I'm not sure if your way will actually cause a service to explicitly be created (though I will test this), I know that with my approach there is.

Which do you think is the more "proper" way to go about this ?

Comment: I think both of the above approaches to launching a service work. A couple of things to remember about services: *A Service is not a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.
*A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors). You may also want to check out the Vogel tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: Vogella's service tutorial is super great and will help me immensly. Thanks, this is a really big help.

Comment: For anyone who decides to run their service in a seperate process, you should see http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Creating-service-in-a-new-process-td5710256.html and comment #4 at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=763